# js-translation.json :404 Not Found

Tags: magento2, error, javascript

I install Magento 2 on IIS 7, it is working good, but on home page and all other pages including admin panel 
a JavaScript error occurred

the error is :

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/js-translation.json"
>   SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>   `$.mage.translate.add(JSON.parse(string));`

then I explore location 
`/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/` and found that the file is there
when open the file it is contain just two square bracket `[]`.

then i delete my old magento store and setup with new magento store with second level  domain.
but still problem is not fixed, but another issue arise my admin penal stopped work.!
now the error look like

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - 
>   http://www.m2.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/js-translation.json"
>       SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>       $.mage.translate.add(JSON.parse(string));

i dont know why magento show that file is not found, because it is already there

I already delete folders in `pub/static` directory and then re-run the deploy command from cmd

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

but it is not work for me.
is magento support IIS 7 ?
is problem occurred due to iis ?

Comment: if you want to get an answer on your question, please, correct it in a clear way

Answer (score 1):

this is an IIS issue to fix it please follow this steps:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Display properties for the IIS Server
3. Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension:

   ```
   File name extension: .json
   MIME type: application/json
   ```
4. Go back to the properties for IIS Server
5. Click on Handler Mappings
6. Add a script map

   ```
   Request path: *.json
   Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
   Name: JSON
   ```

And then browse your json file in broswer, if your IIS setup successfully now you can see the json file content in broswer.